# Performant way of rendering huge list with initial index in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to render a huge list of items using [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) which is using Flatlist.

My question is how do I render the item instantly if its index is let say 100?
The performance is slow if firstItem index is higher with my below code. Considering i already have the data that needs to be rendered.

```
<Carousel
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        itemWidth={WINDOW_WIDTH}
        sliderWidth={WINDOW_WIDTH}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        initialNumToRender={this.state.initialIndex + 1}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
        firstItem={this.state.initialIndex}
      />
```